# How do I replace Ubuntu on a Windows 8 UEFI laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I understand this is an Ubuntu forum so it might be a little weird to ask how to install over Ubuntu, but I thought this might be a good place to ask.

I'm currently dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 8 on a UEFI laptop, but I'd like to try a new Linux distro (won't specify which to avoid being yelled at over my choice or something) and I need my Windows 8 installation and I don't have a ton of disk space so I've decided to just write over my Ubuntu installation.

However, I'm not sure how easy it is to do since it's a UEFI device.  How would I go about doing this?  Would it be the same as installing over Ubuntu on any other dual boot machine?